# count constraint not working laravel eloquent nested relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to put count constraint on laravel eloquent nested relations, but it's not working as expected.

Here scenario is :fetch Hotels those have rooms which are available in date range

```
     $hotels = Hotel::where('destination_id', $destinationId) - > with(['rooms' = > function ($query) use($totalNights, $check_in, $check_out) {
        $query - > with([
                        'dateWisePricing' = > function ($dateWisePricing) use($check_in, $check_out) {
                $dateWisePricing - > where('date', '>=', $check_in);
                $dateWisePricing - > where('date', '<', $check_out);
                $dateWisePricing - > orderBy('date');
                          }
                      ]);
        $query - > has('dateWisePricing', '>=', $totalNights);
                    }
                  ]) - > has('rooms.dateWisePricing') - > get();
```

here it's returning the rooms which are not avuable in date range ( i.e dateWisepricing im empty collection)

any help please

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `whereHas`  instead of only querying the `with` method. But the best option is to query it out with joins like this:

```
$hotels = Hotel::select('hotels.*')
    ->with(['rooms.dateWisePricing' => function ($dateWisePricing) {
        $dateWisePricing - > orderBy('date');
    }])
    ->join('rooms', 'rooms.hotel_id', '=', 'hotels.id')
    ->join('date_wise_pricings', 'date_wise_pricings.id', '=', 'rooms.date_wise_pricing_id')
    ->where('date_wise_pricings.date', '>=', $check_in)
    ->where('date_wise_pricings.date', '<', $check_out)
    ->where('destination_id', $destinationId)
    ->groupBy('hotels.id')
    ->get();
```

This approach will query out all not available record.

**Attention**

Metion that I use: `hotels`, `rooms` and `date_wise_pricings` table names but in fact I dont know how you call them.

Comment: dayWisePricing is relation on room not on hotel

Comment: would you please explain how it's different from my previous code , as it's returning the same result and constrains are also not working as it's before

Comment: Well if you wuery inside `with` then you can only constraint the results of the inside relation (not hotels). If you use joins then you can query out all the records that dosen't has any of the RELATION resaults. If this dosen't works than chacke the date format of `$check_in` and `$check_out` vars.

Comment: anyway i didn't see the use of join query statements,  but once i put the check_in & check_out constrains inside roos.dateWisepricing, then it's returning the results as previously without any change

Comment: i mean to say rooms which are not available between 2 dates are still comming in result set. one doubt where is the constraint for rooms which are available in the given dates